# Count number of elements that match one file with another using AWK

Tags: awk

First of all, thank you for your help. I have the file letter.txt:

```
 A
 B
 C
```

And I have the file number.txt

```
B  10
D  20
A  15
C  18
E  23
A  12
B  14
```

I want to count how many times does each letter in letter.txt appears in number.txt so the output will be:

```
We have found 2 A
We have found 2 B
We have found 1 C
Total letter found: 5
```

I know I can do it using this code, but I want to do it generally with any file.

```
cat number.txt | awk 'BEGIN {A=0;B=0;C=0;count=0}; {count++};{if ($1 == "A")A++};{if ($1 == "B")B++};{if ($1 == "C")C++}END{print "We have found" A "A\n" "We have found" B "B\n" "We have found" C "C"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to do an inner join (easy enough to google) and group by the join key and return the count for each group.

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR { count[$1] = 0; next }
    $1 in count { ++count[$1]; ++total}
    END { for(k in count)
        print "We have found", count[k], k
    print "Total", total, "letters"}' letters.txt numbers.txt
```

All of this should be easy to find in a basic Awk tutorial, but in brief, the line number within the file `FNR` is equal to the overall line number `NR` when you are reading the first input file. We initialize `count` to contain the keys we want to look for. If we fall through, we are reading the second file; if we see a key we want, we increase its count. When we are done, report what we found.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how do I count the total letter found?? @tripleee

Comment: Updated just now; again, not hard to figure out if you spend 30 minutes on a basic Awk intro.

Answer (score 1):

Consider starting with:

```
$ join letter.txt <(cut -d' ' -f1 number.txt | sort) | uniq -c
      2 A
      2 B
      1 C
```

Then:

```
$ join letter.txt <(cut -d' ' -f1 number.txt | sort) | uniq -c |
    awk '
        { print "We have found", $1, $2; tot+=$1 }
        END { print "Total letter found:", tot+0 }
    '
We have found 2 A
We have found 2 B
We have found 1 C
Total letter found: 5
```

although in reality I'd probably just do it all in awk, just wanted to show an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you need awk
to me easier (but slower execution as you read in comments) to use grep -c

```
cat file1 | while read line; do 
  c=`grep -c $line file2 | sed 's/ //g'`; 
  echo We have found $c $line; 
done
```

it's a cycle, where
$c is the count taken with `grep -c`, and sed remove spaces in `grep -c` output

Comment: This will be quite inefficient. Besides the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) you will want to fix the [quoting errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: How you'd write it faster? , You mean quoting `, ' or "?

Comment: You generally want double quotes around all shell variables unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value. Click the link for details; that's why I provided it.

Comment: You are running `grep` again and again on a potentially large file. The Awk solution I provided does all the searching in a single pass over the target file. This is a common FAQ.

Comment: Ok that's fantastic. Great solution. Awk is the best, but i never used it too much, just the basics. Thanks for your tips.

Comment: Quoting errors are very common, even in production scripts by ostensibly professional developers. You would do well to spend some time on understanding how it works; but if you can't or don't want to, http://shellcheck.net/ can offer simple fixes for many common shell scripting errors.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` and `coreutils` can also do this:

```
grep -f letter.txt number.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
      2 A
      2 B
      1 C
```

Comment: This finds the letters anywhere in the line, not just the first field. Fine if the other fields are all-numeric and the keys are always letters, for example; but hard to adapt if not.

Comment: @tripleee: according to OP, there are only letters in the first field